# Using micro frontend end architecture for new project

Tags: user-interface, architecture, asp.net-core-mvc, micro-frontend

I am creating a new project from the scratch using micro front end architecture.
This should be in such a way that,

1. Any micro frontend component created in any technology should be able to embed.
2. Should be able to communicate events between the micro frontends.
3. A composition layer should be there where all this micro frontends are loaded.

To achieve this, i am trying to use the .Net Core MVC as a composition layer, where i will use the micro front ends using the tag helpers.
If there is a situation where a feature to be developed and the developer is not comfortable with any UI technologies, then the development of that specific feature can be done in MVC itself instead of any micro front end.

Is this good approach? Or are there any others better approaches?